# Issue with EASession release on iOS 6.1 which wasn't present in iOS 5.0

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have recently upgraded my iPhone to iOS 6.1 and an app which I developed and successfully ran on iOS 5.0 is now crashing when I release an EASession object.

The following error log appears in the console:

```
-[NSRecursiveLock dealloc]: lock (<NSRecursiveLock: 0x1f5afa00> '(null)') deallocated while still in use
Break on _NSLockError() to debug.
-[NSRecursiveLock unlock]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1f5afa00
```

The line of code which is causing the problem is:

```
[_session release];
```

What's changed in the two versions of iOS which would cause this problem?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did close session before release it? You need to close session first and then release it.

Comment: You can't close the session object itself but you can close the input and output streams which are attached to the session object, which I've done.

Comment: Sorry, I was in the holiday. What I have done is I never call release session directly. I always do close session which is first close input and output and then release session if that session is opened. You know that problem happended when you release session while there is something input and output.

Comment: I have this exact same problem and have traced it to the same place. Did you ever find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)closeSession{

[[_session inputStream] close];
[[_session inputStream] removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[[_session inputStream] setDelegate:nil];
[[_session outputStream] close];
[[_session outputStream] removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[[_session outputStream] setDelegate:nil];
if (_session){
   MCRelease(_session);
}
}
```

(NSRecursiveLock: 0x1f5afa00) deallocated while still in use, this problem is happened when you release session while there is something input and output.

In your code, don't release session yourself, but call closeSession instead. Check the EA Framework example from apple. Hope this will helpful.

Comment: Surely there's no difference between your code and my code?  All that MCRelease(_session) will do is release the _session object in the same way that my code releases it?

Comment: I've looked at the Apple EA code and their closeSession code is the same as mine, in fact that's where my code originated.

Comment: `- (void)closeSession{
    [[_session inputStream] close];
    [[_session inputStream] removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [[_session inputStream] setDelegate:nil];
    
    [[_session outputStream] close];
    [[_session outputStream] removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [[_session outputStream] setDelegate:nil];
    
    [_session release];
    _session = nil;
    
    [_writeData release];
    _writeData = nil;
    
    [_readData release];
    _readData = nil;
}`

Comment: I think you need to give us more detailed information. I am using the same way you did and it is working fine on both ios 5.0 and ios 6.1. It maybe in the other place I believe.